# How to print the Nth column of a text file with AWK using argv

Tags: unix, awk

Suppose I have a text file with data separated by whitespace into columns. I want to write a shell script which takes as input a filename and a number N and prints out only that column. With awk I can do the following:

```
awk < /tmp/in '{print $2}' > /tmp/out
```

This code prints out the second column.

But how would one wrap that in a shell script so that a arbitrary column could be passed in argv?

Comment: It turns out this problem is solved well by cut. Check out "man cut" for more details.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
awk -v x=2 '{print $x}'
```

or in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
num=$1
awk < /tmp/in -v x=$num '{print $x}' > /tmp/out
```

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '{print $'$myvar'}' < /tmp/in > /tmp/out
```

Where $myvar is your variable column (an integer).  Watch out for script injections!

Comment: Or: awk "{print \$$myvar}" ... the advantage being fewer quotes.